# TeamCity 7.1 Jabber notifications do not reach recipient

Tags: notifications, xmpp, teamcity

I'm trying to get TeamCity v7.1 to notify me about build events via Jabber. I have TeamCity on a server at work and I've setup an OpenFire XMPP server on my desktop machine. To complete the picture I have a Pidgin client running on my desktop listening for messages.

I've configured TeamCity to connect to the OpenFire server via an OpenFire user I called "teamcity" and when I "test connection" I am told that the connection is ok. When I'm testing the connection I'm sending to an OpenFire user I called "pidgin".

The problem is that Jabber messages sent from TeamCity never reach the "pidgin" user. TeamCity gives no indication of a problem and I see no sign of a problem in the TC notification log. Much the same way no notification from build events ever gets through to the "pidgin" user (fairly confident I've setup the Jabber notification rules correctly).

Any idea why this is or what I should try next?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is occurring in TeamCity 7.1.4 (build 24331) and YouTrack 4.2 (build 5891).

I'm using Openfire 3.8.1!

YouTrack and Openfire logs show nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've resolved my problem by specifying the "full" XMPP username in TeamCity. In my example: pidgin@urisopenfire (where uriopenfire is the name of my OpenFire server instance).

When I used this full form when testing the connection and in the Jabber Notifier settings for my TC project, I did get notification from TeamCity coming into my Pidgin client.

Oddly enough, this full form is not needed when setting up the "teamcity" user in TeamCity's global Jabber Notification settings.